# what is the different between these two functions in react?

Tags: reactjs, function

I am learning react and in some videos the lecturers use function like this in their component.

```
function(){}
```

and sometimes they use arrow function like this

```
function=()=>{}
```

what are the different between these two? whenever I use function(){} I cannot call any props from state so I always use arrow function and it works very well.

Comment: Some of below answer mentioned about `this` binding, which addresses your question. Just want to share one good article to you https://reactarmory.com/answers/when-to-use-arrow-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrow function automatically binds `this`-context to your component. 
With the normal function you would need to do that yourself in your components constructor like that:

```
this.func = this.func.bind(this)
```

Answer (score 1):

When using the "fat arrow" function, i.e. `myFunc = () => {}`, if you try to access `this` you will receive access to the surrounding function's `this`. This is because the fat arrow function does not `bind` it's own `this`.

When you use `myFunc() {}` you are `bind`ing this and scoping it to that function.